# Getting JSON_PARSER_EXCEPTION "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: saver "

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, cpq

I am trying to use the Quote Generation API for Salesforce, I referred the below link for reference

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_generate_proposal.htm

I am using postman to trigger the below endpoint

URL :

```
https://ap16.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/SBQQ/ServiceRouter?saver=QuoteDocumentAPI.SaveProposal
```

Request Body :

```json
{
    "saver": "SBQQ.QuoteDocumentAPI.Save",
    "model": "{\\\"name\\\":\\\"test\\\",\\\"quoteId\\\":\\\"a0n0R000000jhVC\\\",\\\"templateId\\\":\\\"a0l0R000000vahe\\\",\\\"outputFormat\\\":\\\"PDF\\\",\\\"language\\\":\\\"en_US\\\",\\\"paperSize\\\":\\\"Default\\\"}"
}
```

Response :

```json
[
    {
        "message": "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: saver at [line:1, column:11]",
        "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
    }
]
```

As you can see the above sample request and response. I am getting Json Parser exception.
Can anyone help me out here to figure out where i am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure three `\\\"name\\\":\\\"test\\\"` three backward slash is reqd.

Answer (score 0):

The correct message should be:

```
   {
      "saver": "SBQQ.QuoteDocumentAPI.Save",
      "model": {
        "name": "test",
        "quoteId": "a0n0R000000jhVC",
        "templateId": "a0l0R000000vahe",
        "outputFormat": "PDF",
        "language": "en_US",
        "paperSize": "Default"
      }
   }
```

You don't have to escape double quotes with backshlash when using Postman.